# postgresql - "cut" table data

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, truncate

I need to update one table on my server with data from another table (same columns) on another server. The problem is that I want first table cleaned afterwards, like in the example.

**Before:**

*Table 1* (server 1)

```
 c1 | c2
---------
 a  | 10
 b  | 20
```

*Table 2* (server 2)

```
 c1 | c2
---------
 b  | 30
 c  | 40
```

**After:**

*Table 1* (server 1)

```
 c1 | c2
---------
 <empty>    --emptied
```

*Table 2* (server 2)

```
 c1 | c2
---------
 a  | 10    --inserted
 b  | 50    --updated
 c  | 40
```

How do I achieve that, if *Table 1* is updated every few seconds and I cannot afford to lose any data?

Answer (score 1):

This is really an extended comment.

It seems like `table2` is a summarization of `table1`.

If you want to keep them in sync, then you should use an `update`/`insert` trigger on `table1`.  This trigger would:

- Insert a new row in `table2` if `c1` does not exist.
- Update an existing row in `table2` if `c2` does exist.

This process has a name, "upsert".  In several databases, it is implementing using a statement called `merge`.  Postgres offers two other methods.

The first is to do something of the form:

```
with u as (
      update t2
         set t2.c2 = new.c2 - coalesce(old.c2)
         where t2.c1 = new.c1
      returning *
     )
insert into t2 (c1, c2)
    select new.c1, new.c2
    where not exists (select 1 from u);
```

The second is new functionality in 9.5 that supports the `on conflict` clause in the `insert` statement (documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)).

Finally, I wouldn't recommend deleting rows from `table1` for every change.  Instead, set up a job that deletes them from time-to-time -- once an hour, day, or week.  Deletion can be expensive and you would want to do it when the system is not so busy.